# JSON parse MySQL field with JSON inside

Tags: mysql, ios, database, json, field

sorry if this is a dumb question. My problem is I want make a PHP file that parses in JSON the contents of a MySQL table. The problem is i have a field that have JSON in it with breaklines:

```
 {
"6cb20a9f-27fa-4d98-ac2e-e959eb3f0f63":  {
    "file": "",
    "title": "",
    "link": "",
    "target": "0",
    "rel": ""
},
"43aa1b15-986e-4303-afcf-628b835f10e5":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "<p>This is an example description.<\/p>"
    }
},
"97dacf42-398b-45c5-8536-baec4250b27e":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "2012-10-19 00:00:00"
    }
},
"20fec805-ebb1-4045-9f3d-ea90ad952e91":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "A restaurant"
    }
}
```

}

So at the moment of using the PHP it looks like this:

[PHP Fail](http://diganyo.mx/phpfail.png)

What can I do for it to avoid the \n and \t, because I'm sending this parse to an iphone app and it doesn't recognize it. Thanks!

The PHP Code is something like this:

```
<?php>
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("test") or die("Could not select database");
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"members":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
?>
```

Comment: is this PHP Fail just the raw contents of the field, if so you'd need to json_decode() it

Comment: ups, forgot to put the php code, I just updated the question with the php in it.